# Нужно сделать "прилипание" aside бара к краям браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Чтобы лучше понять вопрос посмотрите как это сделали ребята из Tproger https://tproger.ru/.
У них боковой бар прокручивается и прилипает к краям браузера.
Уже второй день голову ломаю, помогите.[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER0Hu.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте готовую библиотеку
https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `position: sticky;` [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Пример

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.boxes {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum suscipit voluptates rem, mollitia perferendis, molestiae in quis ea, corrupti ad vitae nobis odit labore nesciunt dignissimos. Error consectetur, magnam, rem voluptas libero culpa nostrum
      molestias eos doloremque corporis unde laborum laboriosam. Magni, ut vero soluta ullam quisquam iste nesciunt. Soluta sunt dolorum minus repudiandae cumque deleniti, aspernatur adipisci illum nisi, error autem, quidem delectus deserunt ut quae blanditiis
      doloribus ab! Architecto soluta, esse quidem voluptates laborum quas vero pariatur reprehenderit, atque id. Numquam nisi aliquam dignissimos, quam rem non voluptatum, eum atque, dicta quisquam, nulla obcaecati distinctio perspiciatis illum cum!</p>
  </div>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box">Box</div>
      <div class="box">Box</div>
      <div class="box">Box</div>
      <div class="box">Box</div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer>Footer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed suscipit, vero ut maiores exercitationem impedit id aliquid natus. Reiciendis assumenda expedita nesciunt alias eveniet aliquid nobis ratione dicta obcaecati a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, temporibus eligendi doloremque, aspernatur qui fuga laboriosam error at libero voluptates aliquid cumque veritatis quae tempora, voluptate molestias. Nobis, vitae, rerum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Dolorem inventore eaque, delectus consequatur voluptate repellendus ipsam blanditiis molestiae, commodi velit amet cumque dolor odio, placeat ipsum ut in minima hic.</footer>
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. У меня aside довольно большой, более 100% высоты экрана для laptop. При этом нижнюю часть при скролле страницы я увидеть не могу. Увеличь свой пример на 150% допустим и увидишь, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: @Rettimo - уточните это в своем вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью библиотеки react-sticky-box